# Custom Apache Karaf 4.0.4 distribution with preinstalled pax-jdbc-oracle

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdbc, apache-karaf

I am trying to build a custom karaf distribution with some preinstalled features, because we dont have internet where we would like to deploy it.

This is our pom:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>yolo.name.so</groupId>
<artifactId>karaf</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>

<properties>
    <karaf.version>4.0.4</karaf.version>
    <!-- Karaf Maven Plugin does not have to be same as Karaf Server version
         For example, Karaf Maven Plugin 3.0.2 has bug uploading to password protected Nexus Repo
         So I used Karaf Maven Plugin 3.0.3 to build a Karaf 3.0.2 Server -->
    <karaf.plugin.version>${karaf.version}</karaf.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.reportEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.reportEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <type>kar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.karaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>enterprise</artifactId>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${karaf.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- ignoreDependencyFlag is true forces plugin to also
                download feature dependent libraries -->
                <ignoreDependencyFlag>true</ignoreDependencyFlag>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <bootFeatures>
                    <feature>bundle</feature>
                    <feature>config</feature>
                    <feature>diagnostic</feature>
                    <feature>deployer</feature>
                    <feature>feature</feature>
                    <feature>jaas</feature>
                    <feature>shell</feature>
                    <feature>log</feature>
                    <feature>management</feature>
                    <feature>package</feature>
                    <feature>shell-compat</feature>
                    <feature>ssh</feature>
                    <feature>system</feature>
                    <feature>wrap</feature>
                    <feature>instance</feature>
                    <feature>kar</feature>
                    <!-- custom features -->
                    <feature>war</feature>
                    <feature>jdbc</feature>
                    <feature>cxf</feature>
                    <feature>cxf-rs-description-swagger2</feature>
                    <feature>service</feature>
                    <feature>eventadmin</feature>
                </bootFeatures>
                <!-- installedFeatures only installs the libraries in the ${KARAF_HOME}/system directory
                     but the user will have to start it up manually via Karaf command line feature:install
                -->
                <installedFeatures>
                    <feature>pax-jdbc</feature>
                    <feature>pax-jdbc-oracle</feature>
                </installedFeatures>
                <archiveZip>true</archiveZip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

We always get following error:

```
feature:install pax-jdbc-oracle 
    org.apache.karaf.shell.core[org.apache.karaf.shell.support.ShellUtil] : Exception caught while executing command
    org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=pax-jdbc-oracle; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.7.0,0.7.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=pax-jdbc-oracle)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.7.0)(version<=0.7.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve pax-jdbc-oracle/0.7.0: missing requirement [pax-jdbc-oracle/0.7.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.7.0,0.7.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/0.7.0: missing requirement [org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/0.7.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=oracle.jdbc.pool)"]]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:235)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:158)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:216)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:263)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1089)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:985)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=pax-jdbc-oracle; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.7.0,0.7.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=pax-jdbc-oracle)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.7.0)(version<=0.7.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve pax-jdbc-oracle/0.7.0: missing requirement [pax-jdbc-oracle/0.7.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.7.0,0.7.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/0.7.0: missing requirement [org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/0.7.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=oracle.jdbc.pool)"]]
```

We would like to have this feature preinstalled, but somehow, putting it under bootFeatures or installedFeatures does not matter.

Scope provided / runtime does not matter as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to licensing reason, the feature `pax-jdbc-oracle` can't package the oracle jdbc driver. You have to provide your own copy, and include it in your distribution. This driver is not accessible in maven central, and you can't download it without a license.

See: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Oracle+driver+adapter

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDBC drivers and UCP (Java Connection Pool) are not available on Oracle Maven Repository.

Refer to the following [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for) for instructions to download the JDBC driver from Oracle Maven repository.